# Align icon to text vertically in Ionic 3

Tags: css, ionic-framework, flexbox, ionicons

I'm trying to put a Ionic icon right to text and keep them centered vertically but I'm not able to do that. I'm trying to align the content inside `avg-rating` using flex layout like this:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-card>
    <img src="assets/imgs/restaurant.jpeg" />
    <ion-card-content>
      <div class="title">
        <ion-card-title>
          Title
        </ion-card-title>
        <div class="avg-rating">
          <h2>4,5/10</h2>
          <ion-icon name="star"></ion-icon>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

And this is my SASS:

```
.avg-rating {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  h2 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

And as you can see here, the items are not aligned. I'm used to work with CSS and web apps and this always works, but here it seems that's not working as I'm expecting. Any idea on what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `vertical-align` on the `ion-icon`?

Something like:

```
.avg-rating ion-icon {
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: It does't do anything

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Try to put the elements inside an  instead of  like that:

`<ion-item>
     <h2>4,5/10</h2>
     <ion-icon name="star"></ion-icon>
 </ion-item>`